# Wrongly getting message "Edits were made to the code which cannot be applied while debugging"

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I have searched a lot about the issue and found nothing, i.e. I tried every suggestion that I found to solve it, but none worked.

So as a last resort, I try here..

I am getting

> Edits were made to the code which cannot be applied while debugging.

message, event if I just only add a comment.

I know you cannot modify generic method or add/remove await operators, which would disable debugging session from continuing. But that's not the case.

When I check error list, it is empty.

From what I searched this is known VS bug known for years now, but from what I have read it should be fixed by now (I just updated VS).

**The weird thing is that behaviour occurs only in one solution.**

Has anyone idea on how to tackle this problem, where to look, what to check.

I already tried:

- updating VS
- deleting .vs directory in solution directory
- deleting bin and obj output directory in every project
- cleaning and rebuilding solution
- setting "Enable Edit and Continue" option on and off under Options/Debugging/General tab.
- deleting `*.user` files, I do not have any `*.suo` files

Comment: If this is a VS bug, I reported the issue here
https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/edits-were-made-which-cannot-be-compiled-stop-debu-1/1405828?from=email

Comment: It is just a warning, and tells you that any change you make in .cs files will not be taken into consideration until you leave debugging (as it needs to be recompiled). Or do you mean that you get this message without actually being in debug mode?

Comment: @Rafalon But VS has feature where you cen make changes to code and continue debugging.

Comment: Has it? Never heard of it (I mean I know you can make changes to .cshtml files without having to recompile everything, but .cs files?)

Comment: @Rafalon Yes :)

Comment: Oh right, "Edit and Continue" feature, do you have it enabled?

Comment: @Rafalon See my update :)

Comment: @MichałTurczyn Did you have any prebuild action? Like dotnet format or etc?

Comment: @DmitriyKorolev No

Comment: You don't mention it explicitly, but have you also tried deleting .user files?

Comment: @sellotape Yes.

Comment: That thing is unfortunately still broken in many ways. Sometimes you can change large parts of a method and it works flawlessly, other times you cannot change a comment without this error message. It says that there should be an indication on the cause in the errors window, but usually there isn't. It's been significantly worse in older versions of VS, though.

Answer (score 2):

Is your project an asp.net core web app?

There is an ongoing bug in VS 2019 where:

> If there are two are more .cshtml files with the same name anywhere in your solution then Edit-and-Continue stops working even for simple changes.

Note that having 2 .cshtml files with the same name breaks Edit and Continue throghout the entire project, .cs files included.
See the issue reported [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/1691-and-1692-Edit-And-Continue-Brok/1374733) (and if possible upvote the issue so that it gets more attention from MS).

I had 2 files named "_ViewImports.cshtml" in different folders. Removing one of them restored my ability to edit-and-continue in that project.

Comment: I think the OP talks of normal .cs files.

Comment: @PMF, did you read the issue I linked to? It states that whenever you have 2 cshtml files with the same name, you'll lose the ability to edit and continue throughout the entire project, cs files included (which is what I experienced myself)

Comment: BTW, I found the same issue reported by another user on developercommunity.visualstudio.com, this time it seems to have received more attention from MS. I updated my answer to link to this one.

Comment: Sorry, didn't see that part. I have no cshtml files in _any_ of my projects and still see the issue quite regularly. So might be a hit or not.

Answer (score 0):

Had this issue w/ 16.9.x or 16.10.x (both vs2019) as noted here https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/1691-and-1692-Edit-And-Continue-Brok/1374733. Upgraded to 16.11.12 and finally resolved.

Comment: 16.11.5 is the latest version.